# How to sum up values inside a array variable?

Tags: php

I have retrieved some values from database. In my view file I have the following:

```
 $row['fee_amount'];
```

Now, I want to sum up all the values inside  $row['fee_amount']; and then show it.

I know I could sum up when querying the database, but I am interested to learn how to add using PHP .

Would you please kindly teach me how to do it?

## EDIT

```
    <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>              
        <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>                        
                    <th>S.N</th>
                    <th>Fee Type</th>
                    <th>Fee Amount</th>                         
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>             
                <?php $i = 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?>.</td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['fee_type'];?></td>                                                
                        <td><?php echo $row['fee_amount'];?></td>                                           
                    </tr>                                                                                          
                <?php  } ?>             
            </tbody>                
            <tr>                                                        
                <td></td>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td> 
                    I WANT TO DISPLAY THE SUMMATION RESULT HERE ADDING UP VALUES INSIDE THIS>>> <?  $row['fee_amount']; ?> 
                </td>                                                                               
            </tr>               
        </table>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is your concrete problem? How to sum? How to get all `fee_amount` elements from an array? I guess if you add more of the code you've already done it's more clear.

Comment: Thanks Hakre for you reply. Let me describe the problem. I have fetched data from my database table, and you know when you fetch information from database things come as an array. Now in my view file (I am using Codeigniter) I want to sum up all the values that exist inside $row['fee_amount'];. and then display it. But I don't know how to sum. I am posting my view file above; please check it :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view file, with your `foreach` loop, add a `$sum` variable next to your `$i` counter and add the amount per each iteration (similar to like you increase `$i`):

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($records as $row)
    { 
        $i++; 
        $sum += $row['fee_amount']; ?>
```

(I put this over multiple lines to make it more readable).

After the `foreach` has finished, `$sum` contains the total amount:

```
        <td>Total: <?php echo $sum; ?></td>
```

That simple it is. You only need a new variable (`$sum`) and do the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop

```
$sum = 0;
while($row...){
  $sum += $row['fee_amount']
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use;

```
$someValue = 0;
foreach($row["fee_amount"] as $value) {
  $someValue = $someValue + $value;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that `$row['fee_amount']` is not an array but a single integer value.

Answer (score 0):

using this php function, if  $row['fee_amount'] is an array ^_^

for example:

```
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
array_sum($a)
```