# How to add up a php array that has another array in it?

Tags: php, opencart

How would i get the sum of the totals for the following PHP Array?

I am running this: `print_r($myArray);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 100.0000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 100.0000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 689.5000
        )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried looping over the list, then summing the entries up by using a variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sum up values inside a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285475/how-to-sum-up-values-inside-a-variable)

Comment: have you tried any code so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_reduce`

```
$total = array_reduce($array, function($a,$b) {return $a + $b['total'];});
var_dump($total);
```

You can use `array_map`

```
$total = 0;
array_map(function($v) use(&$total) { $total += $v['total'];},$array);
var_dump($total);
```

Your Just loop

```
for($i = 0, $total = 0; $i < count($array); $i ++) {
    $total += $array[$i]['total'];
}
var_dump($total);
```

Output

```
float 889.5
```

Comment: Thanks that is great! I also had to use floatval($total) to convert it from string to float.